# calculating the index

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ be square free and consider the field extension $K=\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{n}})$ . What is $|\mathcal O_k/\mathbb{Z[\sqrt{n}]}|$?
 , where $\mathcal O_k $ denotes the ring of integers in $K$ .

My idea is to consider the two cases $n \equiv 2,3  \ (4)$ and $n \equiv 1  \ (4)$

In the first case the index is $1$ , in the second case $\mathcal O_k=\mathbb{Z[\frac{1+\sqrt{n}}{2}}]$

Answer (score 1):

For a number field $K := \Bbb Q(\sqrt{d})$ with $d$ squarefree the ring of integers is of the form
$$
\mathcal O_K = \begin{cases} \Bbb Z[\frac{1 + \sqrt{d}}{2}] \quad &\text{if $d \equiv 1 \mod 4$} \\ \Bbb Z[\sqrt{d}]\quad &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}.
$$
This can be deduced from Theorem 3.10 in Stevenhagen's notes, which can be found here: http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/ant.pdf. The proof is an exercise in these same notes.

If $d \not \equiv 1 \mod 4$, then the index is $1$ as you've said.

If $d \equiv 1 \mod 4$ then I claim the index is $2$.

This is because in this case $\mathcal O_K$ is generated by $1$ and $\frac{1 + \sqrt{d}}{2}$. Clearly $\frac{1 + \sqrt{d}}{2} \not \in \Bbb Z[\sqrt{d}]$, so its class in the quotient $\mathcal O_K / \Bbb Z[\sqrt d]$ is different from that of $1$. So the index is at least two.

Now consider some multiple $x = n \cdot\frac{1 + \sqrt{d}}{2}$ of the nontrivial generator. If $n$ is even, then $n \in \Bbb Z[\sqrt d]$, so $x \equiv 1$ in $\mathcal O_K / \Bbb Z{\sqrt d}$. If $n$ is odd, then $n = 2k + 1$ for some integer $k$, and $x = 2k \cdot \frac{1 + \sqrt{d}}{2} + \frac{1 + \sqrt{d}}{2} \equiv \frac{1 + \sqrt{d}}{2}$ in $\mathcal O_K/\Bbb Z[\sqrt d]$.

So the quotient has exactly two classes, and so the index is 2.

Comment: How can I  calculate the index if $d \equiv 1 \ (4)$ ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer . Why is the index 2 ?

Comment: in the last part , why is $x \equiv \frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}$ ?

Comment: @AnabolicHorse Because $2k \cdot \frac{1 + \sqrt d}{2}$ is in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt d]$.